# How to generate a random vector in octave that sums up to a constant?

Tags: octave, probability

I want to generate a random vector such that the elements add up to 1. Is that possible in Octave?

I have a bunch of mutually exclusive events (say 100) and I want to assign random probabilities (non-zero and hopefully with a normal distribution) to them such that their probabilities sum up to 1. Is there a way to do that in Octave?

I know of `rand(1,100)` but I do not know if it is possible to make sure that the values sum up to a constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generate a random vector. It will sum up to `S`. Divide all elements by `S` - it now sums up to `1`.

```
x = rand(1, 100)
x /= sum(x)
sum(x)
# ==> 1
```

EDIT: added code, renamed the confusing variable.

Comment: No, it will not. The only guarantee is that it will sum to something less than `N`

Comment: @Ankit: Are you saying `N / N < 1`?

Comment: try this in octave and see if it comes to 1 `sum(rand(1,12)/12)`. A random vector of N elements will not sum to N.

Comment: I didn't say divide by `12`. I said divide by the sum of the vector, whatever it is.

Comment: Yeah, I can see how my choice of variable names was not exactly stellar. :)